# How to get the list of products of a product promotion class?

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2b

I am working on a function that deals with reviewing the product class promotions, and obtaining the list of the products to which it applies.

```
var promotion = PromotionMgr.getPromotion("alimento-seco-dog-chow");
```

With that line I can bring any promotion, but in the object that it returns I can't find the IDs of the products to which the promotion applies.
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

This information is not obtainable from the promotion side. This for a custom module in the Business Manager to validate promotions?

Comment: It is to schedule a job that checks promotions and adds an attribute to related products. I am analyzing the possibility of exporting promotions and hence the job reads the xml file to find the products of each product class promotion. But I can't find how to read an xml located in the export folder from the job code, any ideas?